Draw a circle from a specified start angle to an end angle at a specified center
I want to draw a circle segment around a center C with a start angle s and an end angle t, where 0 <= s < t <= 360.
Most examples that I have seen use arc command, but that seems unusable because the arc does not start at the center, and any offset needs to recomputed for any choice of s and t.
What is a more usable variant to draw such circular arc around a given center and with given start and end angle? It is also okay I specify only start angle and the offset to the end angle.

Welcome. Have you seen Q123158 and Q705960? If you wand to draw an arc around a center <c> with the start angle <s>, just do ([shift=(<s>:<radius>)]<c>) arc[start angle=<s>, end angle=…, radius=<radius>]. The answers to the linked questions solve this in various ways where you don't have to repeat radii and/or angles.

This is very elementary task for drawing arc. You need to define starting point of arc:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\r{3cm}% circle radious
\coordinate (C) at (1,1);   % circle center

\draw[->]   (-3,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[->]   (0,-3) -- (0,4);
\draw       (1,1) circle[radius=1mm] node[right] {C};

\draw[thick]   (C)                      % circle center
                    ++ (30:\r)          % starting pont
                    arc (30:350:\r);    % start angle:end angle:radius

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I would recommend a syntax that is easier to remember or more self-explanatory:
\coordinate[] (M) at (1,1);
\def\wStart{30}
\def\wEnd{350.25}
\def\R{3.0}

\draw[] ([shift=(\wStart:\R)]M) 
    arc[start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=\R];


\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\coordinate[label=right:$M$] (M) at (1,1);

% An Arc
\def\wStart{30}
\def\wEnd{350.25}
\def\R{3.0}
\draw[|-|,  red] ([shift=(\wStart:\R)]M)
   arc[start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=\R];   

\draw[] (M) circle[radius=2pt]; 
% CoSy
\draw[->]   (-3,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[->]   (0,-3) -- (0,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

